# Zebra Printer prints Invalid C instead of barcode

Tags: zebra-printers, firmware, zpl

**Invalid-C** Is displayed on the label from the Zebra Printer instead of a barcode.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the ZPL sent to the printer either contains invalid characters or the printer cannot find the character in its character set.

Updating the printer firmware fixed this issue.
Go to zebra.com and find the latest firmware for your printer.